# I have a datastudio error - basic json config

Tags: looker-studio

I've returned to try and make some datastudio custom javascript.
So I started off with a template type settings and basic js. Manifest is listing correctly - datastudio sees the custom item.
I took a long time for it to be authorised.
However, on adding the custome js, the console is reporting a load of erros.
first  : data.0.type is not a valid config
second : data.0.elements.data.0.type is not a valid config.

Json:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "idtestviz",
        "label": "Dimension Element Heading",
        "type":"DIMENSION"
      }
    ]
    ,
    "style": [
      {
        "id": "idtestvizstyles",
        "label": "Test Styles",
        "elements":[
          {
            "id":"idtestvizfontcolor",
            "label":"Font Colour",
            "defaultValue":"#FFFF00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

It did have options in before, same error.
And appears to be the same as in https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/define-config

Also it also is erroring on 'is already used in the config'
and that data.0.elements.style.0.elements.0.type required field that cannot be found

Seems like there are more checks that need to be done.
Is there a validator for json etc. before running, or has something updated on google side that their documentation hasn't been updated yet?

Or the more likely aspect, I'm missing some critical stuff...

Regards

Vince

Answer (score 0):

Re checked my json config with a previous one that works, noted some errors in the objects. Corrected those and the json errors in the console have gone away.
JS errors remain - working on those... closing this question.

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "id":"test_viz_data",
      "label":"Test Viz Data",
      "elements":[
        {
          "id": "text_viz_dimensions",
          "label": "Dimension Element Heading",
          "type": "DIMENSION",
          "options": {
              "min": 1,
              "max": 1
          }
        }
        ,
        {
          "id": "test_metrics",
          "label": "Metric fields",
          "type": "METRIC",
          "options": {
              "min": 1,
              "max": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  ,
  "style": [
    {
      "id": "idstyles",
      "label": "Test Styles",
      "elements":[
        {
          "id":"idfontcolor",
          "label":"Font Colour",
          "type":"FONT_COLOR",
          "defaultValue":"#FFFF00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  ,
  "interactions": [       
  ]
}
```